# Django test case ValueError: The given username must be set

Tags: django, django-tests

I am testing a Django application, for its user sign-up feature, whether the posted data is correct and post request executes successfully.

In views.py, the Class CustomerSignUpView

```
class CustomerSignUpView(View):
  def post(self, request):
    name_r = request.POST.get('customer_username')
    password_r = request.POST.get('customer_password')
    email_r = request.POST.get('customer_email')

    contact_number_r = request.POST.get('customer_contact_number')
    profile_picture_r = request.POST.get('customer_profile_picture')

    if checkemail(email_r):
        # receiving an error here in TEST CASE not in actual program execution
        c = User(username=name_r, password=password_r, email=email_r)
        c.save()

        p = Profile(user=c, phone_number=contact_number_r, profile_picture=profile_picture_r)
        p.save()

        return render(request, 'catalog/customer_login.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'catalog/customer_signup.html')

  def get(self, request):
    return render(request, 'catalog/customer_signup.html')
```

This is the test case for user account creation:

```
  class CustomerSignUpViewTest(TestCase):
"""
    Test case for User Sign in
"""
    def test_registration_view_post_success(self):
    """
        A ``POST`` to the ``customer_signup`` view with valid data properly
        creates a new user and issues a redirect.
    """
       data = {
        'username': 'testuser1',
        'password': '1X<ISRUkw+tuK',
        'email': 'foobar@test.com',
        'phone_number': '9876543210',
       }
       response = self.client.post(reverse('customer_signup'), data, follow=True)
       self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
       self.assertTrue(response.url.startswith('/catalog/customer_login/'))
```

The test encounters the following error:  ValueError('The given username must be set')

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sndtcsi/PycharmProjects/Library/catalog/tests.py", line 54, in test_registration_view_post_success
response = self.client.post(reverse('customer_signup'), data, follow=True)
File "/Users/sndtcsi/PycharmProjects/Library/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 535, in post
response = super().post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, secure=secure, **extra)
File "/Users/sndtcsi/PycharmProjects/Library/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 349, in post
secure=secure, **extra)
File "/Users/sndtcsi/PycharmProjects/Library/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 414, in generic
return self.request(**r)
File "/Users/sndtcsi/PycharmProjects/Library/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 495, in request
raise exc_value
File "/Users/sndtcsi/PycharmProjects/Library/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/sndtcsi/PycharmProjects/Library/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/Users/sndtcsi/PycharmProjects/Library/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/sndtcsi/PycharmProjects/Library/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/sndtcsi/PycharmProjects/Library/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/sndtcsi/PycharmProjects/Library/catalog/views.py", line 107, in post
c = User.objects.create_user(username=name_r, password=password_r, email=email_r)
File "/Users/sndtcsi/PycharmProjects/Library/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 150, in create_user
return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
File "/Users/sndtcsi/PycharmProjects/Library/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 139, in _create_user
raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
```

While my sign-up feature works perfectly, the test execution shows that the username is not set. I do not understand why that is happening.

Comment: may that be caused you are waiting key `customer_username`, but posting key `username` in your test?

Comment: not really, I am passing the correct name in the test, i.e. the default name: username

Comment: I mean here - `name_r = request.POST.get('customer_username')` and here `'username': 'testuser1'`. Are u sure this is ok?

Comment: name_r  is a temporary variable which is eventually getting stored in 'username' which is the default field name for User model

Comment: No, I mean key what you get from POST is `customer_username`, but in your TestCase you are posting `username`. What means that in your POST reqest there is no key what you need. To see that you can replace line temporarily `name_r = request.POST['customer_username']` - bet it will make KeyError. OR you can change to `name_r = request.POST.get('username')` - this should work, but make you an error in next line, cuz there is the same problem.

Comment: @Chiefir you should post your comment(s) as the answer (it's of course the issue here).

Comment: @Simran Chiefir is right, you are posting the "username" jey and reading "custom_username" one so it cannot work. Note that you should REALLY be using django forms too (modelforms in your case), those would save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: @Chiefir thanks a lot! the 'customer_username' was the correct way to retrieve the values in my Test Case

Comment: @Sirman, glad to help! you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using bad key in your TestCase. You are trying to get `customer_username` in the form in your view, but you are actually posting `username` key in the *data* in your TestCase. To make this work you should make this lines to use the same keys:

```
name_r = request.POST['customer_username']  
and
'username': 'testuser1',
```

The same problems are with all another forms in this your code.